# i am trying to collapse the nav bar on onclick method but it is not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, ecmascript-6, flux

this is the error from console :

Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWilmount'.

code:

```
    import {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

    import './Header.less';

    import { Button,Navbar, Nav, NavItem, CollapsibleNav,  NavDropdown, NavBrand, MenuItem} from 'react-bootstrap';

    import SearchBar from 'components/search/SearchBar';

    import {LinkContainer} from 'react-router-bootstrap';

export default class Header extends Component {

    static propTypes = {

        flux: PropTypes.object.isRequired,

        searchTerm: PropTypes.string

    };

    state = {
            navExpanded: false
    }

    onNavItemClick = () => {
        this.setState({ navExpanded: false });
    }

    onNavbarToggle = () => {
        this.setState({navExpanded: !this.state.navExpanded});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Navbar fixedTop inverse  toggleNavKey={0} onClick={this.onNavbarToggle()}>
                <Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Brand>
                        <LinkContainer to={"/"}>
                            <a className="navbar-brand"><img alt="######" src={Logo} /></a>
                        </LinkContainer>
                    </Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle />
                </Navbar.Header>
                <Navbar.Collapse>
                    <Nav navbar>
                        <LinkContainer to={"/#####"}>
                            <NavItem onClick={ this.onNavItemClick } eventKey={1}>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</NavItem>
                        </LinkContainer>
                        <LinkContainer to={"/#####"}>
                            <NavItem onClick={ this.onNavItemClick } eventKey={2}>xxxxxxxxxxxx</NavItem>
                        </LinkContainer>
                        <LinkContainer to={"/#######"}>
                            <NavItem onClick={ this.onNavItemClick } eventKey={3}>xxxxxxxxx</NavItem>
                        </LinkContainer>
                        <LinkContainer to={"/######"}>
                            <NavItem onClick={ this.onNavItemClick } eventKey={4}>xxxxxxxxx</NavItem>
                        </LinkContainer>
                        <LinkContainer to={"/######"}>
                            <NavItem onClick={ this.onNavItemClick } eventKey={5}>xxxxxxxxx</NavItem>
                        </LinkContainer>
                    </Nav>
                    <Nav pullRight>
                        <SearchBar onClick={ this.onNavItemClick } searchTerm={this.props.searchTerm} />
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```js
<Navbar fixedTop inverse toggleNavKey={0} onClick={this.onNavbarToggle()}>
```

Instead of passing in the function body `this.onNavbarToggle` you're passing in the *result* of running the function, which is not what you want. The function is being evaluated on every render. You need to pass in a reference to the function, not the result of the function, like so:

```js
<Navbar fixedTop inverse toggleNavKey={0} onClick={this.onNavbarToggle}>
```

Comment: i figured that early that i am passing a function but i need to pass a reference to the variable i have a state that is already public and i am trying to setstate so its not allowing me to do that instead of state if i take any other name and set that variable its working Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here:

```
<Navbar fixedTop inverse  toggleNavKey={0} onClick={this.onNavbarToggle()}>
```

You are calling `onNavbarToggle()` (which updates state) immediately, within `render`. If you reference it in the same way as the `NavItem` and `SearchBar` `onClick` props do (sans invocation) it should work. React is recommending you use `componentWillMount` in case you *do* want to call that method immediately.